# Filtering for Dataframe - columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I want to perform filtering for Pandas Dataframe.
The sample table is like below. For example, I want to filter(remove) all columns which contains the value 2.

```
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
1  1  1  1  4
1  2  1  2  5
1  1  3  1  4
```

I want result table like this. (C2 and C4 removed)

```
C1 C3 C5
1  1  4
1  1  5
1  3  4
```

Also, I want to do this job on rows, using value 5.

```
C1 C3 C5
1  1  4
1  3  4
```

I can do it very easily for single column or row, like **df = df[df.C2 !=2]**, but I don't have good idea for multiple or whole columns and rows.
Is there some simple way for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and specify `axis`:

```
print df
   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
0   1   1   1   1   4
1   1   2   1   2   5
2   1   1   3   1   4

print ~(df == 2)
     C1     C2    C3     C4    C5
0  True   True  True   True  True
1  True  False  True  False  True
2  True   True  True   True  True

df = df.loc[:, ~(df == 2).any(axis=0)]
print df
   C1  C3  C5
0   1   1   4
1   1   1   5
2   1   3   4

df = df.loc[~(df == 5).any(axis=1)]
print df
   C1  C3  C5
0   1   1   4
2   1   3   4
```

Comment: I did't know about any, but it seems to be very useful for handling table. Thank you for your advice.